# Do we assume the piston moves at constant velocity?

Tags: thermodynamics

[image]

When calculating the work done by the surroundings on a cylinder of gas in the setup above, the author uses the formula:

$$\text{Work} = F\cdot\Delta x = \text{pressure of gas}\cdot\Delta x$$

But to my knowledge, the only case where we can replace $F$, the force exerted by surroundings on the piston, with the pressure of the gas inside is if the piston is moving with constant velocity. Is this implied when making this substitution?

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The key word in the description is "quasistatic", meaning the process is happening so slowly that it appears to be static (not moving). Then the gas pressure is always equal to the pressure of the surroundings so there is no acceleration of the piston and its velocity approaches zero.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Are you basically saying that the acceleration of the piston in a quasi-static process is so small that the pressure exerted on the piston by the gas is essentially the same as the applied force F on the piston?

Comment: Basically yes but in the reverse. I’m saying the pressure difference is kept infinitesimal so that the acceleration approaches zero

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not implied that velocity of piston surface is constant. What needs to be implied here is that there is no friction involved in piston movement, hence making work done a path independent function. In this regard, the velocity of the piston or its history of movement may not be taken into account as it does not affect the final state of thermodynamic system.

Comment: The piston also has to be massless for the pressure of the gas to be equal to the outside pressure, or the compression has to be quasi static, as indicated in the figure caption.